# Why order by multiple column caused table scan

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding to postgresql order by.
In my case, I have one table with two column(id, first_name), pk is `id`, also i set an index on clolumn `first_name`.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    ID                  UUID           NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME       VARCHAR(255)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Student_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON STUDENT (FIRST_NAME);
```

when i execute query below: it will trigger an index scan

```
explain SELECT id, first_name
FROM public.student
order by first_name asc
limit 1
offset 0
//Index Scan using index_name on student  (cost=0.14..50.25 rows=140 width=532)
```

also, when i `order by id`, it still trigger an index scan:

```
explain SELECT id, first_name
FROM public.student
order by id asc
limit 1
offset 0
//Index Scan using student_pk on student  (cost=0.14..50.25 rows=140 width=532)
```

My question is, when i use `order by id, first_name`, why it trigger a seq scan?

```
explain SELECT id, first_name
FROM public.student
order by id asc, first_name asc
limit 1
offset 0
//Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=532)
```

I've looked at a lot of PostgreSQL documentation, but I can't find any explains about this. Can someone give me some explain about this phenomenon?

Thank you~

Comment: PostgreSQL can use an index scan to sort the query results, assuming the index matches exactly the columns that are listed in the ORDER BY clause. Since you have indexes on each of the ID column and the FIRST_NAME column, the database can use them to sort the results. But there's no index on both columns together, so if you ask to sort by both of them, the database will not be able to use an index for sorting. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not using the latest version of PostgreSQL, version 13.

If it uses the index on `(id)` alone, then it will need to "read ahead" in the index to find any ties, and if it finds any then it has to go break those ties by looking at `first_name` and resorting to re-sorting.  Doing this was implemented in v13 (called "Incremental Sort"), but not before that.

Of course there can't be any ties on `id` in the first place as it is a primary key, but the planner does not make use of this knowledge.

Comment: Thank you jjanes, according to you answer, i find the documentation here https://postgreshelp.com/postgresql-13-master-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly created a secondary index on `FIRST_NAME`, and also Postgres already created the table with `id` having an index, as this field is the primary key of the table (the clustered index).

When you use:

```sql
order by id, first_name
```

You are requesting a two-tier sort of your data.  Neither the `id` nor `FIRST_NAME` index alone can satisfy this sort.  Actually, using either index would require doing seeks back to the main table to find the values for the alternate column.  As a result, Postgres is choosing to not use any index at all, and just scan the table.  Note that your current result might change depending on the size of the table and type of the data.

Comment: I'd still expect it to use the `id` index, and look at `first_name` only when there are multiple rows with the same id - this should require much less work memory in general.

Comment: @Bergi Well we don't know the OP's exact data.  It could be structured in such a way that the index is not beneficial.  Or perhaps the table have a small size and therefore Postgres was already on the fence as to use any index.

Comment: That sounds like a more likely explanation to me (the question says 140 rows?).

Comment: My answer still stands though.  It uses an index which completely covers the sort, but won't use an index which doesn't cover the sort.

Comment: Thank you Tim~Actually,  in my production system, there are about 600 million rows in such a table. Order by clause is like `order by creationDate desc, id asc`, and `id` is pk, `creationDate` is an index. It triggers a seq scan. I saw postgresql documentation, they said I need to set up an index like (crationDate desc id asc), then it can trigger index scan. I already tried this, it's the truth. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-ordering.html

Comment: But I think the document is not detailed enough, I just want to get some more information about "why order by multiple indexed columns cannot trigger an index scan". Now I think I already got the answer, as jjnes said -- the version of postgresql before 13 are not provide the feature named "Incremental Sort". see here https://postgreshelp.com/postgresql-13-master-guide/